# Good book on EMC and EMI

Tags: emc, emi-filtering

I'm looking for a good book about EMC and EMI.

There are plenty of books talking about norms and standards, but I'm looking for a book focusing on understanding the logic and physics behind it. And how to design filters and housings to reduce EMC and EMI issues.

Thanks.

Comment: Hol Wi - Hi, FYI the tag info for "book" (which you didn't add, so you may not have seen this) says: "*Please do not ask for book recommendations!*" Those questions used not to be disallowed, but they are now. There is some background about the change in policy, in the answers to [this](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6512) meta discussion. || If you search this site for *emc book* (and similar terms) you will find that some answers do include suggested books.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Fast Circuit Boards Energy Management

https://www.google.co.in/books/edition/Fast_Circuit_Boards/GIBDDwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=high+energy+boards&printsec=frontcover

EMI Filter Design

https://www.google.co.in/books/edition/EMI_Filter_Design/H37y0HIyd4oC?hl=en&gbpv=1&printsec=frontcover

Introduction to electromagnetic compatibility

https://www.google.co.in/books/edition/Introduction_to_Electromagnetic_Compatib/GUjStAEACAAJ?hl=en

Electromagnetic Compatibility Engineering

https://www.google.co.in/books/edition/Electromagnetic_Compatibility_Engineerin/07rFwAEACAAJ?hl=en